# remote webdriver: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: webdriver, thucydides

I use **JAVA** + **WebDriver** (Thucydides) and **Maven**.

I'm trying to automate uploading of a file. If I launch test manually from IDE it passes, but when I launch it with Maven on Remote WebDriver the test fails halfway with the error:

```
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebdriverAssertionError: Element is not currently visible and so may   not be interacted with
```

The browser is FireFox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at screenshot in Thucydides report. It seems that your element is really not visible.

Comment: There is no screenshot for that step

Comment: What the version of your thucydides? You can make screenshot before the step. And anyway you can take screenshot manually, just cast webDriver to TakesScreenshot. Are you sure that your Remote WebDriver is configured properly? It looks like the wrong page or something like this.

Comment: Version of thucydides is **0.9.77**. Where can I configure Remote WebDriver? The only thing I've done for configuring remote driver is set **webdriver.remote.url** property.

Comment: I've managed to make screenshot of falling step and there is nothing wrong with the page. Thucydides opens the very page I want but fails after `UploadPage().open();`

Comment: Yes, you have to define webdriver.remote.url and add the system property -Dwebdriver.driver=remote. So, if you did it, try to wait for your element using explicitly wait.

Comment: Is it neccesary to add  the system property -Dwebdriver.driver=remote. ? Cuase when I did this test maven shew an error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class net.thucydides.core.webdriver.SupportedWebDriver.REMOTE.`